# How do I install PyYaml on windows 10?

Tags: python, pyyaml

It seems to be a required module for several other modules.
I'm on windows 10 64 bit and have Python 3.5, Python 3.6-3.2 and Python 3.6 installed.

I tried `pip3 install --upgrade pyYaml` but the error is

```
Collecting pyYaml
  Using cached PyYAML-3.12.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: pyYaml
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pyYaml ... error
  Failed building wheel for pyYaml
  Running setup.py clean for pyYaml
Failed to build pyYaml
Installing collected packages: pyYaml
  Running setup.py install for pyYaml ... error
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\whatever\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\compat\__init__.py", line 73, in console_to_str
    return s.decode(sys.__stdout__.encoding)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8a in position 76: invalid start byte


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:




Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\whatever\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\users\whatever\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "c:\users\whatever\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "c:\users\whatever\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 878, in install
    spinner=spinner,
  File "c:\users\whatever\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 676, in call_subprocess
    line = console_to_str(proc.stdout.readline())
  File "c:\users\whatever\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\compat\__init__.py", line 75, in console_to_str
    return s.decode('utf_8')
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8a in position 76: invalid start byte
```

Yes I'm aware of the other question with the same title, but their solution doesn't work for me.

Running `pip3 install PyYAML-3.12-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl` says `PyYAML-3.12-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel for this platform`, nothing more.

I also tried with several different wheel file versions from the site. Also all these things I tried both with pip and pip3.

I also downloaded the .exe installer and that ran nice, and it automatically saved it in the python35 path, but then I don't know ho to use it, it doesn't happen anything.

I'm very new to python so i'm kinda stuck as it just doesn't work.

like wtf

Comment: On Windows, the Anaconda distribution of Python makes more sense. Try with it if you don't mind. Use its conda installer for this purpose.